# Python:Retain memory address of object after __str__ method has been implemented

Tags: python, string, class, object

How can I retain the address of object after I implemented **str** method on a class

```
class X:
    pass

x=X()
print(x)

#<__main__.X object at 0x000000A63773C5B0>hexadecimal value here I want to be able to bind to some variable 

class X:
    def __str__(self):
        objinfo='X object is located at {}'.format(argument here I wish to be hexadecimal value produced before __str__ method is implemented on a class)
        return objinfo
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think that `id(object)` gives you the address of an object, converts it to hexadecimal with `hex()`.

```
class X():
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
    def __str__(self):
        objinfo='X object is located at {}'.format(hex(id(self)))
        return objinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

Before showing the answer, I'm really not sure if this works, but I'm pretty sure it does !

```
class X:
 def __str__(self):
  return hex(id(self)).upper()

x = X()
print(x)
```

Here, "id" function, return a unique number, for that precise object."hex" function, simply transform it in hexadecimal !

I'm pretty suree it gives the adress !